# 3D template matching by opencv

Tags: image-processing, opencv, template-matching

I have a 3D matrix (very large, let call it L) and a 3D small one (very small, let call it S) and want to use OpenCV to find the closest pattern in L.

Does OpenCV do it for me? If yes, how I should use it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, OpenCV doesn't have anything for this.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/), which is an open source library to work with 3D data. I can tell you from my experience, that learning to use this library is very similar to learning OpenCV because many developers work for [Willow Garage](http://www.willowgarage.com/pages/software/overview), the main sponsor of OpenCV.

If you go to the PCL [tutorials](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/) you will find three useful sections to solve your problem:

1) finding [features](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#features-tutorial) in your 3D point cloud, that you can later use for matching

2) 3D [object recognition](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#recognition-tutorial) based on correspondence grouping

3) Point cloud [registration](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#registration-tutorial) using methods like iterative closest point, and feature matching

Answer (score 1):

Do you have sparse pointcloud or just 3-dim matrix?

For 3-dim matrix you can use phase correlation using FFT. Good library is [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/)

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has added some neat tools to accomplish this kind of task

- Surface Matching https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d25/group__surface__matching.html
- Silhouette based 3D tracking https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc4/group__rapid.html
- Convolutional Neural Network https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d02/group__cnn__3dobj.html